# C++ find an element in a map

Tags: c++, oop, find, string-comparison, stdmap

Hello,

```
typedef map<MedDept, int, findDepartment> temp;
typedef temp::value_type temp_type;
     
MedDept md1("Test1", 3, "Physio info");
MedDept md2("Test2", 4, "info");
     
temp t;
    
t.insert(temp_type(md1, 2));
t.insert(temp_type(md2, 3));

cout << t.size() << endl; // 2
```

The above code works perfectly, however, when I try to find one the elements as follows:

```
if (t.find(md2) != t.end()) {
   cout << "found" << endl; 
} else {
   cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```

It returns not found

but when trying to find md1 as follows.

```
if (t.find(md1) != t.end()) {
   cout << "found" << endl; 
} else {
   cout << "not found" << endl;
}
```

It works and returns the object.

Any ideas of what might be the issue. Thanks

Here is the compare operator

```
bool findDepartment::operator( ) ( const MedDept & md1, const MedDept & md2 ) const {
    return (md1.getDepartmentName().compare(md2.getDepartmentName()) != 0);
}
```

Comment: Your `findDepartment::operator()` is incorrect, you should use `std::less` or `operator<` and not `compare(..) != 0`.

Comment: But I'm comparing strings here. Am I missing something?

Comment: There are correct and incorrect ways to compare. Your way is incorrect. You can in fact use `compare` function, just not the `!= 0` part. Replace it with `< 0`.

Comment: Yes, `std::map` has strict ordering.  You are defining a custom comparator that guarantees that ordering.  The compartor is used in place of `std::less`, and you can make it do whatever you want _PROVIDED_ it follows standard conventions such as `findDepartment()(a, b) != findDepartment()(b, a)` if `a` and `b` are different.  In fact, this is how equality is determined -- if the function returns the same value regardless of the ordering of its arguments, then the value is considered equal.  As currently written, yours will consider _ALL_ values to be equal.

Comment: The "comparison" function used by `std::map` isn't actually a comparison function, it's an *ordering* function, which is used to check is one object is *less than* another object. And it needs to follow [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Comment: Thank you guys, I got the idea now and the code works 

Comment: A less operation can be used to evaluate all necessary other comparison operations:
`a == b : !(a < b) && !(b < a)`, `a != b : (a < b) || (b < a)`, `a > b : b < a`, `a <= b : (a < b) || !(b < a)`, `b <= a : (b < a) || !(a < b)`